# Required type capture of ?, provided T

Tags: java, generics

Why does calling `val.isValid(request)` gives a compile error `Required: type capture of ?, provided: T`?
How can I fix the error?

```
public class RequestValidator implements IRequestValidator{
    private Map<Class<?>, IValidator<?>> validatorMap;

    public RequestValidator() {
        validatorMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> void registerValidator(Class<T> clazz, IValidator<T> validator) {
        validatorMap.put(clazz, validator);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> boolean validate(T request) {
        if (validatorMap.containsKey(request.getClass())) {
             IValidator<?> val = validatorMap.get(request.getClass());
             return val.isValid(request);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

`IValidator` interface:

```
public interface IValidator<T> {
    boolean isValid(T t);
}
```

Comment: What is the type signature of `isValid()`? Which library are `IValidator` etc from? If that's a popular library, tag accordingly to attract the experts.

Comment: it's my own defined interface.

Comment: This can't be done in a type-safe way. You must do an unsafe cast somewhere, for example: `IValidator<T> val = (IValidator<T>)validatorMap.get(request.getClass());`

Comment: How about `return ((IValidator<T>) val).isValid(request);` to get an unchecked warning and resolving this.

Comment: Is it possible to cast from `MyClass<?>` to `MyClass<T>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably not going to get around casting in this case, meaning this is how the `validate` method would look like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public <T> boolean validate(T request) {
    if (validatorMap.containsKey(request.getClass())) {
        IValidator<T> val = (IValidator<T>) validatorMap.get(request.getClass());
        return val.isValid(request);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I've tried it before. Still got the similar error: 
`Required type: capture of ?, Provided: Object`

Comment: I've updated my answer. It's not pretty, but probably the best possible.

Comment: Is it possible to cast from `IValidator<?>` to `IValidator<T>`?

Comment: It should be. You'll have to test it though.